# AWS SSL Certificate installed in load balancer prevents access to php pages?

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, elastic-load-balancer

I am using  an AWS EC2 Ubuntu server.Recently i installed an ssl certificate provided by aws certificate manager using aws load balancers.
Once the ssl was successfully installed i am unable to access specific php pages eg: domainname/admin.php or vendor.php. 
I get re-routed to index page (index.php)
Kindly suggest any solution or pointers for this issue?

The webpage is accessible and the ssl is working fine.The web browser seems to prevent php page access.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to disable https and rewriting rules on your web server for https(if enabled). then you can access you admin panel and perform the following steps :-

1. In the administration panel, go to Settings > Security settings.
2. In the Enable secure connection for the storefront setting choose Secure full site.
3. Click the Save button.

then you can enable your rewriting rules with https again. 
i hope it helps?